# Publish Stream from the application - for non logged in user, using Graph API, php SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using graph api publish_stream permission: together with offline_access permission:

As described [here](http://facebookanswers.co.uk/?p=214) and [here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4814432/publishing-to-users-wall-without-being-online-logged-in-facebook-sharing-usin). However for some reason one of the following two things are happening:

I am trying to post to a facebook user which is not currently logged in, following an action of a user which is curently logged in (e.g. telling user #1 that user #2 visited their farm in farmville, but user #1 is not logged in, while user #2 is. And they are not necessarily friends).

When I tried this using the following code, the post was not created when users #1 and #2 were not friends (first problem), and when they were friends, the post was being created, but seemed like user #2 was posting it on user #1's wall (second problem - this is NOT what I am trying to do, I want it to be anonymous).
See the first code I used:

```
    $post_id = $facebook->api('/' . $user1_id . '/feed/', 'post', array(
    'message' => 'Someone just visited your farm',
    'link' => 'http://example.com',
    'picture'  => 'http://example.com/img/picture.jpg',
    'caption' => 'Visit farms!'
    ));
```

So I tried to use the access token of user #1, which he gave me when he was logged in, and the application is supposed to be able to post on their wall even when they are offline (even without offline_access permission - see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) facebook's documentation: "you can publish... without requiring offline_access". At any rate, when I am adding the access_token to the array as a parameter (see the code below), no post is being created at all:

```
    $post_id = $facebook->api('/' . $user1_id . '/feed/', 'post', array(
            'access_token' => $user1_access_token,
    'message' => 'Someone just visited your farm',
    'link' => 'http://example.com',
    'picture'  => 'http://example.com/img/picture.jpg',
    'caption' => 'Visit farms!'
    ));
```

What should I do?

gain, I am simply trying to publish to user's wall that is NOT logged in, but who gave me the publish_stream permission, a post from the application, not any other user, telling this user that someone (anonymously) has "visited their farm" (or created some action associated with them).

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is just a recommend & i'm not sure this be the answer 
Destroy all of the sessions (or use your browser in private mode -for Firefox )
& then visit sender page Like this

example.com/postfarm.php

maybe when you visit the page normally the app gets your access_token & tries to post as you

PS:better way

use this code & you dont need to destroy sessions anymore

```
    include_once ('src/facebook.php');/// include sdk
    ////// config The sdk
        @ $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => 'XXXXXXX',
        'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
         ));
$facebook->destroySession();
    try{        
    $post=$facebook->api('USER_ID/feed/','POST',array(
    'message' => '$message',
    'link'=>'http://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxxx/link.php?link=',
    'picture'=> 'XXXXXXXXXX',
    'name'=>'XXXXXX',
    'description'=>'yes',

    ));
    }
    catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo $e->getType();
    echo '<br />';
    echo $e->getMessage();
     }
```

Comment: hi! so, this works in "private browsing" in firefox, but i want to add it to my code, and I tried destroying sessions and it didn't work. how should I do that? thanks!

Comment: you can use this to destroy Facebook sessions  `$facebook->destroySession();`

Comment: I tried crontab and it worked, now I'm trying facebook destroy session, hope it works too.

Answer (score 1):

For the "someone did something in a game and it's your turn", I believe what you're looking for is requests 2.0, specifically the  "App to user" communication.

from: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/

> App to User Requests can be used to re-engage a user in your app and
>   can only be sent to users that have installed the app. For example,
>   notifying a user that something has changed since their last visit,
>   "10 of your friends are now online".
>
> App to User Request are sent via the Graph API, for more information
>   see the apprequests docs. App to User Requests are only available for
>   Canvas apps, not websites, as accepting a request will direct the user
>   to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request.

from: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/

> App-generated requests: These requests can be initiated and sent only
>   to users who have authorized your app. You should use these requests
>   to update the bookmark count to encourage a user to re-engage in the
>   app (e.g., your friend finished her move in a game and it’s now your
>   turn).

Comment: Correct, since you didn't specify, I assumed you have the most common type of Facebook app ... the canvas app.  If you don't have something that standard, you should state that clearly in your question so your question has a higher chance of being answered correctly.   BTW, Facebook frowns upon apps that send automated (non user interactive and fixed text) messages like this to the walls of users. You should check out their policies, or your app might get shut down.

Comment: this is not automated, it is activated by a user