# Unset cookies (not working)

Tags: php, cookies

Good morning,

I have tried a lot of codes in order to unset some cookies from a simple PHP form, but it's impossible. I tried with "unset", then I tried with "setcookie with a negative date", but they are still in my browser.

How can I unset the cookies? That's how I set the cookies:

```
setcookie("name", $name, time()+120);
```

That's how I'm trying to unset the cookies:

```
setcookie('name',null, -1, '/');
```

Why they are still in my browser?

Thanks,

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP documentation has examples of.

```
// set the expiration date to one hour ago
setcookie ("TestCookie", "", time() - 3600);
setcookie ("TestCookie", "", time() - 3600, "/~rasmus/", "example.com", 1);
```

http://php.net/setcookie

Perhaps try the following, otherwise you're going to need to start inspecting the raw http request headers/responses for issues.

```
setcookie('name', '', time() - 3600);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the following links , better to search but to ask a question which has been asked before :

[Link #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401654/delete-cookie-in-php)

[Link #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686155/remove-a-cookie)

Comment: I have already searched and testes a lot of threads from Stackoverflow, but it didn't worked...! Regards,

Comment: Have you tested your app in another browser ?
seems a problem not from code but somewhere else